# math_ops.floor equivalent in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, floor

I'm trying to implement a custom layer in Keras where I need to convert a tensor of floats `[a, 1+a)` to a binary tensor for masking. I can see that Tensorflow has a `floor` function that can do that, but Keras doesn't seem to have it in `keras.backend`. Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: I think you won't have a problem if you use `tf.floor`. Do you get any errors if you use it? Using backend functions is necessary in those cases when there is a need to pre- or post-process the argument passed to actual function in Tensorflow or Theano. Or if you want to write a code that works across all the Keras backends.

Comment: That did work, thanks! If you can add it as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As requested by OP, I will mention the answer I gave in my comment and elaborate more:

**Short answer:** you won't encounter any major problems if you use `tf.floor()`.

**Long answer:** Using Keras backend functions (i.e. `keras.backend.*`) is necessary in those cases when 1) there is a need to pre-process or augment the argument(s) passed to actual function of Tensorflow or Theano backend or post-process the returned results. For example, the [`mean`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/f9210387088fe91b5bc8999cf0cb41a0fe9eacf6/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L1368) method in backend can also work with boolean tensors as input, however the [`reduce_mean`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_mean) method in TF expects numerical types as input; or 2) you want to write a model that works across all the Keras supported backends.

Otherwise, it is fine to use most of real backend functions directly; however, if the function has been defined in `keras.backend` module, then it is recommended to use that instead.

Comment: I do not really get what you in your first 1). Why is ```mean``` function an example of your point ?

Comment: @BenDes If you take a look at its implementation (which I have linked to in my answer) you will find that a casting is done for the values of type `bool` and then the `tf.reduce_mean` is called. However, depending on your application and usecase, you may find this unnecessary and prefer to use the backend function directly (i.e. call `tf.reduce_mean` directly).

Comment: Oh okay, I thought that when you were talking about pre-process, it was something else than the fact to transform ```bool``` in ```mean```.
Thanks