# Keras backend (tensorflow) vs Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to custom a Keras loss function but I do not really understand something.

If I use tensorflow as a backend for Keras, do I need to use functions from `keras.backend` or can I use functions directly from tensorflow.

I only see posts where people are using functions from `keras.backend` but not from tensorflow (even if tensorflow has much more functions). Are there reasons to do so?

For a toy example :

```
from keras import backend as K 
import tensorflow as tf

def loss_keras(y_true, y_pred):

    square_error = K.square(y_pred - y_true)
    loss = K.mean(square_error)

    return loss

def loss_tf(y_true, y_pred):

    square_error = tf.squared_difference(y_pred, y_true)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(square_error)

    return loss
```

Both of these functions work well but one is using directly tensorflow and the other is using `keras.backend` functions.

I know that this is a silly example but when you want to do more complicated stuff, I thought that using tensorflow would be easier than keras functions as there are more functions available

Comment: If you use the keras backend, your code will run with all of the supported keras backends and not only tensorflow. If you use the tensorflow functions directly, your code will not run with for example a theano backend.

Comment: @BenDes You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52186294/2099607) useful.

Comment: thanks to both of you !

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in the comments and stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52184478/math-ops-floor-equivalent-in-keras/52186294#52186294) "using Keras backend functions (i.e. keras.backend.*) is necessary in those cases when 1) there is a need to pre-process or augment the argument(s) passed to actual function of Tensorflow or Theano backend or post-process the returned results or  2) you want to write a model that works across all the Keras supported backends."