# How can I use tensorflow.python.ops in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm looking to do SVD for a custom optimizer in Keras (specifically, I want to port the [the Shampoo optimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/opt/ShampooOptimizer) to Keras.

In Tensorflow, I would use `tensorflow.python.ops.linalg_ops.svd()`, however, there is no function like this in `keras.backend`.

Can SVD be carried out in a purely Keras setting, or can I somehow use the Tensorflow function directly (and if so, how)?

**EDIT**: Just for future reference, there actually exists a wrapper function allowing the direct use of a native tf optimizer in Keras:

```
import keras as ks
from tensorflow.contrib.opt import AdamWOptimizer

tfopt = AdamWOptimizer()
ksopt = ks.optimizers.TFOptimizer(tfopt)
```

Unfortunately though, it does not seem to work with the Shampoo optimizer specifically.

Comment: Did you figure out how to use the shampoo optimizer in Keras?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using keras with a tensorflow backend, than keras backend *is* tensorflow.
This means that when you call a method from keras backend, it actually calls a method of tensorflow.

Therefore you could use both keras backend operations and tensorflow together and interchangeably.

For example, in the given code:

```
tensor = ...
m = K.mean(tensor)
...
```

I could change the line `K.mean(tensor)` to `tf.mean(tensor)`

```
tensor = ...
m = tf.mean(tensor)
...
```

So you can just use the tensorflow SVD operation as you would use it if it was a function of keras backend :)

For example if you would like to have

```
tensor = ...
res = K.some_submodule.svd(tensor)
...
```

Than you can instead just do

```
tensor = ...
res = tensorflow.python.ops.linalg_ops.svd(tensor)
...
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't think there is a one-to-one correspondence between `tensorflow` and `keras.backend`. For instance, I can do the following import `from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops`, but not `from keras.backend.python.ops import array_ops`. Why is that?

Comment: That's a good point, and I understand i have to clarify myself. I did not try to claim that keras has all the functionality that tensorflow has, or that keras.backend is exactly equal to using tensorflow. What i meant to say is that when you use keras above tensorflow, is uses methods that are implemented in tensorflow. This means that the objects keras uses are objects that can be tensorflow direct methods can work with as well. Therefore you can mix direct tensorflow methods with keras.backed methods.

Comment: Do you agree with the above claim? Or do you still see any issues with it? :)

Comment: I'm still a bit unsure that pure TF and Keras always just mix. The most notable example I can think of it that a TF tensor and a Keras tensor are not the same thing (the Keras tensor carries its history with it). But that is perhaps only an issue when constructing a graph?

Anywho, what I'm actually trying to do is to implement a specific optimizer (inheriting from the Keras Optimizer class), which needs SVD. If that isn't possible using pure `keras.backend`, does that mean I cannot write my optimizer in Keras such that it would be natively compatible with any backend?

Comment: Another good point. All i can say is that i've already written functions that contained tensorflow methods and integrated them with a pipeline written in keras. For example i've made a custom loss function that contained tensorflow methods. My opinion is that it should work if you use tensorflow methods, but i have no further ways to prove it.

Comment: @OfficialThrowaway (or @BobsonDugnutt) I see you've accepted the answer. did it work for you than? :)

Comment: I haven't tested it yet, but I think this answers the question sufficiently for now, so I accepted it to close the question. However, I will say that comments such as your last are generally not constructive, and just fill up the comments section - the accept should tell you enough. Cheers.

Comment: I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52184478/math-ops-floor-equivalent-in-keras/52186294#52186294) answer. It seems to be exactly what you look for